# Cannot assign value, SwiftUI fetch API

Tags: ios, swift, api

I wanted to grab data from exchangeratesapi.io, but I have been struggling with modeling my data.
it says "Cannot assign value of type 'rates' to type rates.Type"

I have no idea what I did nor have any visualization , if there's any reference please do comment below.

Here's my class

```
class MoneyView:ObservableObject {
    @Published var currency = rates.self//[rates]()
    
    init() {
        fetchData()
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=24a5ab7688a7044f60bfeb491eb37550") else {
            return
        }
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let safeData = data {
                    do{
                        let result =  try decoder.decode(rates.self, from: safeData)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.currency = result // here's the error
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Here's the rates type :

```
struct rates: Decodable{
    // USD CAD IDR GBP CHF SGD INR MYR JPY KRW
    var USD:Int
    var CAD:Int
    var IDR:Int
    var GBP:Int
    var CHF:Int
    var SGD:Int
    var INR:Int
    var MYR:Int
    var JPY:Int
    var KWR:Int
}
```

in case you guys wonder how the API looks like

```
{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1620597364,
  "base":"EUR",
  "date":"2021-05-09",
  "rates":{
    "AED":4.469059,
    "AFN":93.55172,
    "ALL":122.991702,
    "AMD":629.683505,
    "ANG":2.167635,
    "AOA":795.883245,
   }
}
```

Comment: Apart from what was written in the answer below you also need to change the type of all your properties from Int to Double

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@Published var currency:Rate?


struct Root: Decodable{
   var rates:Rate
}

struct Rate: Decodable{
    var USD:Int
    var CAD:Int
    var IDR:Int
    var GBP:Int
    var CHF:Int
    var SGD:Int
    var INR:Int
    var MYR:Int
    var JPY:Int
    var KWR:Int
}
```

---

```
let result =  try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: safeData)
 currency = result.rates
```

Change class start letter to capital `Rates`

Comment: why do i neeed to capitalized it?? anyway xcode gave an error that says "cannot find scope"

Comment: `struct Rates: Decodable{`

Comment: somehow it works, but i cannot grab the api